# Build Error in Ant +Ivy project in Jenkins

Tags: ant, jenkins, ivy

I am new to jenkins and am trying to build an Ant+Ivy project using jenkins and have configured Java_Home as C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21.I have pasted the console output.

```
09:38:47 
09:38:47 BUILD FAILED
09:38:47 Target "Files" does not exist in the project "abc". 
09:38:47 
09:38:47 Total time: 0 seconds
09:38:47 Build step 'Invoke Ant' marked build as failure
09:38:48 Archiving artifacts
09:38:48 Finished: FAILURE
```

PS: I have checked that targets called are present in build.xml and also I am able to run it from the windows console.I believe the problem is the space between Program and Files(may be ant considers "files" as target).Please Help!

Comment: are you filling up the "Build File" with the absolute path or not?
IF absolute, then make relative. E.g. abc/target_name

Comment: As I thought it was due to the space between Program and Files in the path.I gave my directory paths without spaces and it works fine now.@EyadEbrahim :Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I thought it was due to the space between Program and Files in the path.I gave my directory paths without spaces and it works fine now.